# What is the value of Jacobian when transform from Cartesian coordinate to Cartesian coordinate?

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, jacobian

when $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1, x_2, \cdots x_n)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y_1, y_2, \cdots y_n)\cdot|J_g|\cdot dy_1dy_2\cdots dy_n$, both $f$ and $g$ Cartesian coordinate but different position(rotated), will Jacobian matrix will be 1?

Comment: Yes, the determinant of a rotation is equal to $1$.

Comment: could you please prove that?

Comment: Don't quote me on this one, but I think that rotations are - **by definition** - precisely the linear transformations with determinant equal to $1$. But even if this wasn't part of the definition, it should be clear from the geometric interpretation of the determinant. I hope you know what I mean.